# Remote execution

Tags: shell, remote-execution, rexec

I have been working on **rexec** for a few days!!

So the task is like this. I have server A and server B. I want to run a shell script on **server B** which is triggered from **server A**. The script that I use will be like

*From server A* 
rexec serverB script.sh argument

*Script.sh in server B*
       f1=$1
       echo "unload to test.unl select * from table where key in ($first)"|dbaccess DB
       cat test.unl

when I run thescript.sh in server B it has no problem at all.

When the same is run from server A, it says **dbaccess not found**. Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably a PATH issue. Type `which dbaccess` on server B, and use that complete path in your script.

Comment: Got the issue resolved!! I forgot to export few environment variables that I have used in **sever A**.

@ckhan: Thanks!!!